# is it possible to simulate fluid/water spilling from cup/container using three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to simulate a cup with water in it with real physics making the water spill when the cup is tilted

Something like this:
https://prnt.sc/QUYpkvP1E2Ki

What would be a good resource ? I tried looking into the three.js examples directory and found nothing similar